# collectionView didSelectItemAt indexPath not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When attempting to select a cell in my collection view, nothing happens. I have my delegate set up but it does not get called when the user taps.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("cell selected")
}
```

The cell is a custom cell containing a CAShapeLayer and a UILabel. I have attempted to mess around with the `isUserInteractionEnabled` method to no avail.

In addition, I can sometimes get the `"cell selected"` message to print if I tap really fast but it is very seldom. Let me know if you have any suggestions!

```
func drawCircle() {
    var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: (frame.size.height / 2.0) - 15)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: (frame.size.width - 20) / 2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0), clockwise: true)

    circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "Fourth")?.cgColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 8.0

    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
}
```

Comment: may be problem due to CAshapeLayer can you post code for custom cell class

Comment: Are you setting the frame to the CAShapeLayer? make sure which ever class contains "didSelectItemAt indexPath:" is the delegate to the collectionView that contains your custom cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by setting `cancelsTouchesInView`method to `false` on a `UITapGestureRecognizer` I have. Full code below.

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideKeyboardByTappingOutside))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```